# fprintf saves wrong data to file

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have an input file `a.txt`:

```
1 abc 3
2 efgh 4.5
3 text 3
4 xyz 2
```

So basically, it has 3 columns, first one is int, second is text, and third is double. I need to read this file by rows (which actually works, I guess), but have some problems with writing only second and third column to another (`b.txt`) file. `fprinft` saves something like this:

```
 0.000000
 0.000000
 0.000000
 0.000000
xvæ$ 0.000000
```

instead of

```
abc 3
efgh 4.5
text 3
xyz 2
```

I simply need to save only the second and the third column from `a.txt` file to `b.txt` file. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mypair
{
    char string[1024];
    double number;
} mypair;

void zero_string(char *string, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        string[i] = '\0';
}

int row(FILE* f, struct mypair *p)
{
    int num;

    if(!feof(f))
    {
        if(fscanf(f,"%d %s %lf", &num, p->string, &p->number) == 3)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 5, status = 0, i = 0, j;

    struct mypair array[5];
    char file_in_name[255];
    char file_out_name[255];

    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fout;

    zero_string(file_in_name, 255);
    zero_string(file_out_name, 255);

    printf("Data file:\n> ");
    scanf("%s", file_in_name);
    printf("Out file:\n> ");
    scanf("%s", file_out_name);

    fin = fopen(file_in_name, "r");
    fout = fopen(file_out_name, "w");

    if( fin == NULL )
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    if( fout == NULL )
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(status != 1)
    {
        status = row(fin, &array[i]);
        i ++;

        fprintf(fout, "%s %lf\n", array[i].string, array[i].number);

        if(i >= n)
            break;
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    for(j=0; j<i; j++)
        printf("%s %lf\n", array[i].string, array[i].number);

    return 0;
}
```

I modified the code, now it works, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mypair
{
    char string[1024];
    double number;
} mypair;

void zero_string(char *string, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        string[i] = '\0';
}

int row(FILE* f, struct mypair *p)
{
    int num;

    if(!feof(f))
    {
        if(fscanf(f,"%d %s %lf", &num, p->string, &p->number) == 3)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 5, status = 0, i = 0, j;

    struct mypair array[5];
    char file_in_name[255];
    char file_out_name[255];

    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fout;

    zero_string(file_in_name, 255);
    zero_string(file_out_name, 255);

    printf("Data file:\n> ");
    scanf("%s", file_in_name);
    printf("Out file:\n> ");
    scanf("%s", file_out_name);

    fin = fopen(file_in_name, "r");
    fout = fopen(file_out_name, "w");

    if( fin == NULL )
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    if( fout == NULL )
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("\n");

    while(status != 1)
    {
        status = row(fin, &array[i]);

        if(i >= n)
            break;
        else
        {
            if(status != -1)
                fprintf(fout, "%s %lf\n", array[i].string, array[i].number);
        }

        i ++;
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    for(j=0; j<i; j++)
        printf("%s %lf\n", array[j].string, array[j].number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). You don't use the exact same constructs but you have the same problem.

Comment: Your `row` function doesn't always return a value.  When the `fscanf()` fails, you don't return anything, so you get random gibberish returned.  Your code does not protect itself from a file with more lines than it has storage for.  This leads to problems.  Always make sure you do not access memory out of bounds of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bottom loop, you want to index your array by j, not i.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how its possible that I have not noticed it!